Calculate HC3 robust vcov matrix when knowing only of Gradient and Hessian matrices of a GLM model
Suppose that a Generalized Linear Model is fitted using Maximum-Likelihood Estimation, but we only have access to two results from it:

the gradient matrix $G$ is a $n \times p$ matrix where each row $g_i$ represents the gradient of the log-likelihood with respect to the parameters for each observation $i$.

the hessian matrix $H$ is a $p \times p$ matrix of second derivatives of the log-likelihood function with respect to the parameters.

the hat matrix $A$, of dimensions $n \times n$.


Then, the variance-covariance matrix with HC0 robust adjustment, $V_{HC0}$, can be found by:
$$V_{HC0} = H^{-1} (G^{T}G) H^{-1}$$
What about the HC3 adjustment? How could one calculate the HC3 variance-covariance matrix without having access to the residuals or to the fitted values of the GLM model?

Side note: Once you get into Bayesian modeling you end up spending your time on model specification and interpretation and spending no time on approximations such as what you are exploring.
